# Cannot declare variable to be an abstract of class

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++. I'm trying to create another object but it somehow block me from doing so. It has this cannot declare variable 'rq' to be of abstract type 'Rectangle' because the following virtual function are pure within 'Rectangle'.

here is the library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
```

this is the superclass

```
class Shape {
protected:
char area[20][20];
int htri,ss,width,length;

public:
virtual void printRectangle() = 0;
virtual void printSquare() = 0;
void sethtri(int t){
    htri = t;
    }

void setss(int s){
    ss = s;
    }

void setwidth(int w){
    width = w;
    }

void setlength(int l){
    length = l;
    }

int gethtri(){
return htri;
}

int getlength(){
return length;
}

int getwidth(){
return width;
}

int getss(){
return ss;
}

};
```

this is one of the subclass

```
class Rectangle:public Shape
{
protected:
int raziq;
public:
void printRectangle()
{

raziq = rand() % 21;
    for (int i = 0 + raziq; i <= length + raziq; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 + raziq; j <= width + raziq; j++)
    {
            area[i][j] = 'C';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++)
        {
            if (area[i][j] != 'C')
            {
                area[i][j] = '-';
            }

        }
    }

for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        cout << area[i][j];
    }
cout << endl;
    }
}
};
```

this is another subclass

```
 class Square:public Shape
{
protected:
int raziq;
public:
void printSquare()
{

raziq = rand() % 21;
    for (int i = 0 + raziq; i <= ss + raziq; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 + raziq; j <= ss + raziq; j++)
    {
            area[i][j] = 'C';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++)
        {
            if (area[i][j] != 'C')
            {
                area[i][j] = '-';
            }

        }
    }

for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        cout << area[i][j];
    }
cout << endl;
    }
}
};


int main(){

int t,s,w,l;
ofstream keluar;
ifstream masuk;
masuk.open("value.txt");
if (masuk.is_open())
{
    cout << "File value is open \n";
    masuk >> t >> s >> w >> l;
    masuk.close();

}
else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

the error is right here on Rectangle rq

```
srand(time(NULL));
Rectangle rq;
Shape *s1 = &rq;
s1->sethtri(t);
s1->setlength(l);
s1->setss(s);
s1->setwidth(w);
s1->printRectangle();

Square sq;
Shape *s2 = &sq;
s2->sethtri(t);
s2->setlength(l);
s2->setss(s);
s2->setwidth(w);
s2->printSquare();





  return 0;
```

}

Comment: You are not asking a question. Anyhow, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, when you present problems with code, you should extract a [mcve].

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if `printSquare` is called on a `Rectangle`? You didn't tell the compiler!

Comment: why you are overrding the printsquare() function in the rectangle class and vice versa ? it makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

> If we do not override the pure virtual function in derived class,
>   then derived class also becomes abstract class.

Rectangle is derived from shape and shape contain two pure virtual function , so you have to implement both  `printRectangle()` and `printsquare()` functions in the rectangle class . otherwise it will also become abstract class

you need to implement the `printsquare()` method also in the rectangle and square class , then  you can make an object of these classes.

```
class Square:public Shape
{
    public:
    void printRectangle() override;
    void printSquare() override;
};

class Rectangle:public Shape
{
    public:
    void printRectangle() override;
    void printSquare() override;
};
```

why you are overrding the `printsquare()` function in the rectangle class and vice versa ? it makes no sense

source [Abstact class c++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

Better practice is to add override keyword in signature of overriding function in derived classes. In this case compiler will give error if by mistake signature is getting changed in derived class.

In this case:

```
class Shape
{
    public:
    virtual void printRectangle() = 0;
    virtual void printSquare() = 0;
}

class Square:public Shape
{
    public:
    void printRectangle() override;
    void printSquare() override;
};
```

see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Answer (score 0):

Your design is questionable!

1. Assume you want to add further shapes, e. g. `Circle`, `Ellipsis`, `Triangle`, perhaps a generic `Polygone` – do you really want to extend the base class each time you add a new shape (`printCircle`, `printTriangle`, ...)???
2. [Hamza.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10815377/hamza-s)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54157285/1312382) (this is the one to the question as given, I am looking a bit further here...) already shows up why you couldn't instantiate child classes, fixing the issue by letting derived classes override *all* pure virtual functions. But why should a circle print a square, a triangle a rectangle, ... That's just meaningless.

So you should consider a complete re-design:

```
class Shape
{
    public:
    virtual ~Shape() = default; // important: add a virtual destructor!!!
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape
{
public:
    void print() override; // prints a square
};
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    void print() override; // prints a circle
};
```

About protected members: You should only retain those members that *every* shape needs. A square will only need one of width and length, a circle will need none of, but a radius instead, triangle needs at least three parameters to uniquely identify it.

If you only have squares and rectangles and are 100% sure that you won't add other shapes, it might be meaningfull to retain more of these members (and the getters/setters to) in the base class – but that's up to you to decide...

Comment: Nice answer but my answer was what the  questionnaire wants .